# Gradient and Hessian of square of Lp-norm $\| \mathbf{x}\|_p^2$, where $1 \leq p<\infty$

Tags: matrix-calculus

What are the gradient and Hessian of square of any Lp-norm $\| \mathbf{x}\|_p^2$, where $1\leq p<\infty$? One could assume that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ (But I think one can also consider $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ if it is convenient to find the solution.)

I found one paper, which shows the gradient of an Lp-norm as following -- see Equation (7) and (14) herein https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.06986.pdf.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
f(\mathbf{x}) & \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) & \nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x})\\
\hline
\| \mathbf{x}\|_p^2 & \left(\| \mathbf{x}\|_p^{2-p} | \mathbf{x}|^{p-2} \right) \circ \mathbf{x} & ?\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
where $\circ$ denotes element wise multiplication.

I don't know how they have derived it even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\bbC#1{{\mathbb C}^{#1}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\abs#1{\op{abs}\LR{#1}}
\def\sign#1{\op{sign}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Generalize the problem to a complex matrix $X\in\bbC{m\times n}$

Define the real-valued matrix $A=\abs X\;$ and note that
$$\eqalign{
&A\odot A = X\odot X^* \\
&{dA\odot A} + {A\odot dA} \;=\;  {dX\odot X^*} + {X\odot dX^*} \\
&{A\odot dA} \;=\; \tfrac12\LR{X^*\odot dX + X\odot dX^*} \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product and $X^*$ is the complex conjugate.

The $L_p$ norm (to the $p^{th}$ power) can be written using
the all-ones matrix $J$

and Hadamard powers of $A$
$$\eqalign{
L_p^p &= J:A^{\odot p} \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the scalar Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
B:C\: &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n B_{ij}C_{ij} \;=\; \trace{B^TC} \\
B:B^* &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
}$$
The gradient can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
p\,L_p^{p-1}\:dL_p
 &= J:\LR{p\,A^{\odot p-1}\odot dA} \\
 &= J:\LR{p\,A^{\odot p-2}\odot A\odot dA} \\
 &= p\,A^{\odot p-2}:\frac12\LR{X^*\odot dX} \;&+\; conjugate \\
dL_p &= \fracLR{X^*}{2L_p}\odot\fracLR{A}{L_p}^{\odot p-2}:dX
 \;&+\; conjugate \\
\grad{L_p}{X}
 &= \fracLR{X^*}{2L_p}\odot\fracLR{A}{L_p}^{\odot p-2} \\
\grad{L_p}{X^*}
 &= \fracLR{X}{2L_p}\odot\fracLR{A}{L_p}^{\odot p-2} \\
}$$
Of course, when $X\in\bbR{m\times n}$ these results can be simplified
$$\eqalign{
&\;{A\odot dA} = X\odot dX \\
&\;dL_p = \fracLR{X}{L_p}\odot\fracLR{A}{L_p}^{\odot p-2}:dX \\
&\grad{L_p}{X} = \fracLR{X}{L_p}\odot\fracLR{A}{L_p}^{\odot p-2} \\
}$$
and setting $n=\o$ recovers the vector case.

Finally, your question was about the **square** of the norm,
which would be
$$\eqalign{
\grad{L_p^2}{X} &= 2L_p\gradLR{L_p}{X} \\\\
}$$

### Update

In the general $\bbC{m\times n}$ case, there are **four** possible Hessians
$$\eqalign{
\def\hess#1#2#3{\grad{^2 #1}{#2\:\p #3}}
\hess{L_p}{X}{X},\quad\hess{L_p}{X^*}{X},\quad
\hess{L_p}{X}{X^*},\quad\hess{L_p}{X^*}{X^*} \\
}$$
I doubt you are interested in these, so I concentrate on
the $\bbR{m\times n}$ case.

We'll need the elementwise self gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad{X}{X_{kl}} = E_{kl},\qquad M_{kl}=M:E_{kl} \\
}$$
where all components of $E_{kl}$ are zero except for the
$(k,l)$ component which equals $\o$.

Its Frobenius product with any matrix produces the
$(k,l)$ component.

Calculate the differential and gradient of $G$ (aka the hessian)
$$\eqalign{
\def\h{\odot}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
q &= p-2 \\
G &= L_p^{\o-p}\LR{X\odot A^{\odot q}} \\
dG
 &= L_p^{\o-p}\LR{X\odot dA^{\odot q}+A^{\odot q}\odot dX}
 + \LR{X\odot A^{\odot q}}\LR{\o-p}L_p^{-p}\;dL_p \\
 &= L_p^{\o-p}\LR{qX\h A^{\h q-\o}\h dA+A^{\h q}\h dX}
 + \LR{X\h A^{\h q}}\LR{\o-p}L_p^{-p}\;dL_p \\
 &= L_p^{\o-p}\LR{qX\h A^{\h q-2}\h\c{A\h dA}+A^{\h q}\h dX}
 + \LR{X\h A^{\h q}}\LR{\o-p}L_p^{-p}\;dL_p \\
 &= L_p^{\o-p}\LR{qX\h A^{\h q-2}\h\c{X\h dX}+A^{\h q}\h dX}
 + \LR{X\h A^{\h q}}\LR{\o-p}L_p^{-p}\;dL_p \\
 &= L_p^{\o-p}\LR{qA^{\h q}\h dX+A^{\h q}\h dX}
 + \LR{X\h A^{\h q}}\LR{\o-p}L_p^{-p}\;\c{dL_p} \\
 &= \LR{\o+q}L_p^{\o-p}A^{\odot q}\odot dX
 + \LR{\o-p}L_p^{-p}\LR{X\odot A^{\odot q}}\;\CLR{G:dX} \\
\grad{G}{X_{kl}}
 &= \LR{\o+q}L_p^{\o-p}\LR{A^{\odot q}\odot E_{kl}}
 + \LR{\o-p}L_p^{-p}\LR{X\odot A^{\odot q}}\;\LR{G:E_{kl}} \\
 &= \LR{p-\o}L_p^{\o-p}\LR{A^{\odot q}\odot E_{kl}}
 - \LR{p-\o}L_p^{-p}\LR{A^{\odot q}\odot X} G_{kl} \\
}$$
The components of this expression are the
components of the Hessian
$$\eqalign{
{\large\cal H}_{ijkl}
 &= \hess{L_p}{X_{ij}}{X_{kl}}
  = \hess{L_p}{X_{kl}}{X_{ij}} 
  = \grad{G_{ij}}{X_{kl}} \\
 &= \LR{p-\o}L_p^{\o-p}\:{A^q_{ij}\,\d_{ik}\d_{jl}}
  - \LR{p-\o}L_p^{-p}\:{A^q_{ij}X_{ij}}\,G_{kl} \\
}$$
If you are only interested in the vector case, keep the $(i,k)$ indices and drop the other two. This makes the Hessian a matrix with components
$$\eqalign{
{H}_{ik}
 &= \hess{L_p}{x_{i}}{x_{k}}
  = \hess{L_p}{x_{k}}{x_{i}}
  = \grad{g_i}{x_k} 
  = \grad{g_k}{x_i} 
\\
 &= \LR{p-\o}L_p^{\o-p}\:{a^q_{i}\,\d_{ik}}
  - \LR{p-\o}L_p^{-p}\:{a^q_{i}x_{i}}\,g_{k} \\
}$$
Narrowing the scope to the **square** of the norm
of a real vector
$$\eqalign{
\def\hessLR#1#2#3{\LR{\hess{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
&\hess{\LR{L_p^2}}{x_i}{x_k}
  \;=\; 2\,L_p\hessLR{L_p}{x_i}{x_k}
  \;+\; 2 \gradLR{L_p}{x_i} \gradLR{L_p}{x_k}^T
}$$

### Update 2

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$As Steph points out in the comments, the results (for real vectors)
can be simplified by using a diagonal matrix to eliminate Hadamard products and powers (and index notation)
$$\eqalign{
\def\g{{\large g}}
\def\A{{\large\cal A}}
\def\L{L_p}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\A &= \Diag{\frac{\abs{x}}{\L}} \\
\g &= \A^{p-2} \LR{\frac{x}{\L}} \\
H &= \frac{p-\o}{\L}\:\LR{\A^{p-2} -\, \g\g^T} \\
}$$

Comment: At first glance, it looks intimidating -- I must say. However, after pondering over, I can follow this. I wonder how difficult it would be to compute the Hessian. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Greg, in the vector case, this can be written in a more symmetrical way as $\mathbf{H}
=
(p-1) \left[ L_p^{1-p}  \mathrm{Diag}\left(\mathbf{a}^{\odot(q)}\right)
- L_p^{-1}  \mathbf{g}\mathbf{g}^T \right]$

Comment: @greg: I thought I understood the steps of Hessian. But I was redoing it, then I got stuck at the second line of $dG$. In particular, how did you get the first component $\left( 1 +q\right) L_p^{1-p} A^{\odot q} \odot dX$?

Comment: @learning I expanded the derivation. How does it look?

Comment: @greg Thank you so much! This is perfect! Wow!

Answer (score 2):

Start by writing the function in terms of the components:

$$f(\mathbf{x}) =(|x_1|^p +|x_2|^p+\dots +|x_n|^p)^{2/p}$$
Now, take the derivative with respect to $x_i$ (using chain rule):
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} =p |x_i|^{p-1} \color{red}{\operatorname{sgn}(x_i)}\frac{2}{p}(x_1^p +x_2^p+\dots +x_n^p)^{2/p-1}$$
(Recall that the derivative of $|x|^p$ is $p|x|^{p-1}\operatorname{sgn}(x)$).

The last expression can be cleaned up a little bit:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = 2|x_i|^{p-2}\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert_p^{2-p} x_i $$
which is the result that you are looking for (expect that there is a $2$ here that was not in the paper).

---

For the Hessian, you can do the same thing, you just need to compute the derivative

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} $$

Comment: +1. We are taught chain rule in this university. However, I must admit that I am always making sloppy mistakes with chain rule. How about Hessian?